# Display style tag in angular js while translation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-translate, angular-sanitizer

This is my controller file wherein

```
$scope.htmlCompanyFromScope = '<span style=color:red>Micro</span>';
$scope.htmlTagFromScope = "MicroTag";
```

My *.resx file contains

```
 TranslationValue = "{{htmlCompany}} tag is {{htmlTag}}"
```

And in my `HTML` I define the following:

```
 <span translate="TranslationValue " translate-values="{htmlCompany: htmlCompanyFromScope , htmlTag: htmlTagFromScope}"></span>
```

But in the end, the style is not honored. 
Displays something like

**Micro tag is MicroTag**

any pointers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using `sanitize` strategy for escaping like:

`$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');`

[It uses](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/19_security#escaping-of-variable-content_general-use) [`$sanitize`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) service, so style attributes will [get stripped by this service](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10406) (and to overwrite this you'll need to change the source code of `angular-sanitize.js`, but I don't recommend doing this). As a workaround here - you need to use `class` attributes (since class attributes are not stripped with `$sanitize`) like `class="red"` and set proper css styles like `.red { color:red; }`.

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CaTwd56j7y9TZChKqtLk?p=preview).

Comment: Exactly.. +1 for figuring out that the sanitizeValueStrategy was 'sanitize'. Thanks. introduced class and changed css to include that style.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<span style="color:red">
```

not

```
<span style=color:red>
```